# An Exception occur in Tablayout

Tags: android

I wanna add three layout in a TabActivity, but it was force closed when I ran it.

### Here is the code:

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class Test1 extends TabActivity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Resources res = getResources(); 
     TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();      

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("egcquery").setIndicator("EGCQuery").setContent(R.layout.main1)); 
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("PatientInfo").setIndicator("PatientInfo").setContent(R.layout.main2)); 
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Comp_Interp").setIndicator("Comp_Interp").setContent(R.layout.main3));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this question: [Why do I get an error while trying to set the content of a tabspec in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941241/why-do-i-get-an-error-while-trying-to-set-the-content-of-a-tabspec-in-android/2941481#2941481)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I change this it is still force closed :(
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("egcquery").setIndicator("EGCQuery").setContent(R.id.L1)); 
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("PatientInfo").setIndicator("PatientInfo").setContent(R.id.L2)); 
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Comp_Interp").setIndicator("Comp_Interp").setContent(R.id.L3));

Comment: Did you add the corresponding android:id tag to your xml layout files?

Comment: Yes, I've already added. Like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/L1" 
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="186px" 
    android:layout_height="29px" 
    android:text="This is Layout1"
    android:layout_x="70px" 
 android:id="@+id/text1" 
 android:textSize="24sp"
 android:layout_y="32px" 
    
    />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: What exception are you getting now?

Comment: I just see "The application Test1(process irdc.test1)has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". Could you tell me how to find the reason??

Comment: Try single stepping through your code in the debugger and see when it fails.

Comment: In the Debugger window , the "Method.invokeNative" and "NativaStart.main" lines show that can't be used.

Comment: At first I put three Activity in a TabActivity and it can works. But I wanna set TextView in Tab2 by clicking a button in Tab1. An member tell me use layout is much easier, no Activity.  I've tried but it didn't success util now :( .